# Why is the NewConnectionCount so high for my ELB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm running an ELB on my EC2 in the free tier.  I have a domain with a wildcard (*.domain.com) pointed at my ElasticIP on the Application ELB.  It runs fine most of the time (NewConnectionCount less than 10) and it's in development.

However, for no apparent reason, periodically the NewConnectionCount spikes to 1500 and stays there for hours, or days at a time.  There is not an associated request spike at the time.  I don't know what this even means, let alone how to fix it.  I've tried playing with the configuration (I run a node server on the EC2), but all attempts have failed.  Specifically, I tried opening up a target group for port 3000 for direction connection to the node server (via port 443), as well as using iptables to route port 443 traffic to port 3000 (via port 80).

Another potential issue I have is that I have a certificate (using Certificate Manager) for the same wildcard domain on a different site.  I don't see why that would be a problem, but I'm grasping at anything at this point.

While it might be too much to ask anyone to solve my problem, I'd be appreciative if someone could give me a plausible scenario why the connections would spike so much.  It might help me in my search.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you reviewed the logs for your ALB?

Comment: They weren't enabled.  Right now it's running fine so I'll have to wait until the next spike before I'm able to get useful data.

Comment: This is very common due to bad actors hitting your site. I will bet that the ELB log files will show lots of hits to your site generating 404s, hitting commonly known login locations, database locations, possibly denial-of-service, etc. If this is the case, then setup WAF to start blocking these attacks. WAF requires ALB or NLB. ELB is not supported.